# Add an event to GestureDetector

Tags: java, android, webview, gesturedetector

Actually i have GestureDetector for a WebView, it's works, i can change the page to load by left and right swipe but zoom, pan and active links has stopped to work. This is the listener:

```
private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener sogl = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("Gesture","onDown");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (event1.getRawX() > event2.getRawX()) {
                if(currentPage<maxPage)
                    currentPage++;
                webV.loadUrl("file:///sdcard" + Values.APP_FOLDER + "/" + catalogo +"/versione-html/" + currentPage + estensione);
            } else {
                if(currentPage>1)
                    currentPage--;
                webV.loadUrl("file:///sdcard" + Values.APP_FOLDER + "/" + catalogo +"/versione-html/" + currentPage + estensione);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

The question is: can i add this single event (left and right swipe) to the webview default GestureDetector? I need to zoom and keep active links on the webview and also change page with swipe.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try returning false in `onFling`.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but I would consider sending all the touches you receive inside the GestureDetector down to the WebView via `webV.onTouchEvent(event)`